# Why does firefox generate multiple <tspan> for white spaces and how can I prevent it

Tags: html, firefox, svg, axis, c3.js

I've run into an issue with Firefox
(yes, the usual culprit is IE but he behaves nicely this time).

I'm using the c3 API to generate a bar chart, and formatting the tick value
of the time (x) axis with this [moment](http://momentjs.com/) format - `MMM D, YYYY`
(it also happens with plain text, but I rather write exactly what I did).

Both Chrome and IE display the tick in one line (e.g. "Oct 3, 2003")
but Firefox breaks it into two lines (note there's no space after the comma) -
`Oct 3,
2003`

Even worse -
the second line is cut at half-height due to the graph's height.

I've checked the issue in the DOM structure,
and found out that in both Chrome and IE the content is inside of a `<text>` element,
while Firefox splits the content of the `<text>` element into several `<tspan>` elements
(all influenced by the white-spaces which are being deleted).

I've checked Dr. google and can't find yet a way to force FF not to split the text.

I'll appreciate any help (greatly)

Update: [here is the jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/shnozzle/L1b47kdd/23/) of a graph (disregard the fact that it has no columns data).

Comment: I think we're going to need a [mcve] to have any chance at answering this.

Comment: Thanks for your note and sorry for not providing earlier.

Comment: Its look like a C3 issue. You can debug the C3 and see how it acts. My guess is that in FF it found its don't have much space for the whole text so it breaking it to pieces based on white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

please check the updated jsfiddle:-

https://jsfiddle.net/L1b47kdd/26/

i just removed the format in y axis and this issue is fixed in firefox. please check..

```
format: d3.format("d")
```